# how to set background service on cordova for deny disconnecting?

Tags: android, cordova, signalr, background-service, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I'm developing a hybrid app using cordova. For notifications, I created a SignalR server on my ASP.Net Web Server and my mobile application is connected to my SignalR server for runtime connection.
I wanna run a background service for receive notifications when app is closed. I have tried [cordova-plugin-background-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-background-service) but it doesn't work on any situation.

 Does anyone can help me?